# Reading data from keyboard to store in string array

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

```
String s[];
System.out.println("Enter loop value");
int t = s.nextInt();
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
{
 str[i]=s.nextLine();
}
```

while it reading it gives null pointer exception

Comment: does this code even compiles ?

Comment: compilation fails : null pointer exception

Comment: what i have to modify or give other choice of code to read strings from keyboard and store them in string array

Comment: You didn't assign the array `s` any values, so of course it will be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is something like this:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter loop value");
    int t = s.nextInt(); // read number of element
    s.nextLine(); // consume new line
    String str[] = new String[t];
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
     str[i]=s.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Enter loop value");
    String a[] = new String[Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = br.readLine();
    }
```

Comment: Why? This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Just example how to store String from keyboard to array of Strings

Comment: @mikeyaworski - To be fair, they didn't ask a question.

Comment: @RudiKershaw It's obvious... we don't need to play games and make excuses. This is a bad answer.

Comment: @mikeyaworski - It's not a great answer, there are better against this question. But its a good example of 'Reading data from keyboard to store in string array'. And that is ultimately what this question is about.

Comment: @RudiKershaw No it's not (what the question is ultimately about). The OP clearly shows that he can read in lines and store them to an element in the array. His only problem is that his array was null. Now the answer is slightly better, but still not what the OP needs.

Comment: @mikeyaworski- All right, whatever you say. But the end result is identical.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the typos and missing declarations in your code:

```
package snippet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        String str[] = new String[10];
        System.out.println("Enter loop value (maximum 9)");
        int t = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i <= t; i++) {
            str[i] = s.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("your entered lines:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
    }

}
```

However, I would recommend to store the values in a `List` instead of an `Array`. I also prefer using a `BufferedReader` to using a `Scanner`.

Comment: You hardcoded the length of the string array to be 10. BAD. The opposite of what he wants.

Comment: if we enter 9 and takes 9 values but it need to store 10 values----gave input like this a b c d e f g h i output gives [,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]

Comment: As mentioned in my post I would recommend to store the values in a `List` instead of an `Array`. This will prevent those problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
//After modifying my code works well
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Sample 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    bufferedReader();
            scanner();
}
    static void bufferedReader()throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter Number of Strings");
            int len = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            String a[] = new String[len];
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
                System.out.println("Enter String"+ (i+1));
        a[i] = br.readLine();
    }
            for(String str : a)
            System.out.println(str);
    }
    static void scanner(){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Number of Strings");
            int len = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
            String a[] = new String[len];
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
                System.out.println("Enter String"+ (i+1));
        a[i] = s.nextLine();
    }
            for(String str : a)
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

But when using Scanner nextLine() skips the data when read
if any one knows please post description with example