# load data from keyboard to arraylist of objects (object has multiple parameters)

Tags: object, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to load up data from the user/keyboard (using a scanner) to an arraylist of objects. My constructor (student) has 6 parameters but each of these needs to be added in separately by the user (they can't do this all at once). I know how to do this if the object only has one parameter, but not when there are multiple parameters. I'm not sure how to save the data I get from the user to the array if I'm not getting all six parameters from the user at once:

```
//constructor in Student class. 
Student (String sFirstName, String sLastName, int iHWAve, int iQuizAve, int iTestAve, int iProjectAve)
{
    super(sFirstName, sLastName);
    this.iHWAve=iHWAve;
    this.iQuizAve=iQuizAve;
    this.iTestAve=iTestAve;
    this.iProjectAve=iProjectAve;
    Student.this.CalcGrade();
}

//code from main method
ArrayList<Student> aoStudent = new ArrayList <>();

    int iStudCount;
    int iNumStudents;

for (iStudCount=0; iStudCount<iNumStudents; iStudCount++)           
    {   
        //these are the prompts for the data I need to get from the user
        System.out.println("Enter in the first name for Student "+(iStudCount+1));
        System.out.println("Enter in the last name for Student "+(iStudCount+1));
        System.out.println("Enter in the Quiz Average for Student "+(iStudCount+1));
        System.out.println("Enter in the HW Average for Student "+(iStudCount+1));
        System.out.println("Enter in the Test Average for Student"+(iStudCount+1));
        System.out.println("Enter in the Project Average for Student "+(iStudCount+1));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay assuming you want to achieve this in Java? (because in your snipped is some "System.out.println" and "this" stuff)

Im not aware of a keyboard input mechanism for arrays.

If the "objects" are from the same type this would work:

[Reading data from keyboard to store in string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346306/reading-data-from-keyboard-to-store-in-string-array)

But you are talking about Java Objects or different types (int, String, etc...)? Im also not aware of how a User can enter a Java Object that easy...because Java is statically typed...this means the compiler need to know the type he is dealing with before...(if you don't like this...maybe check out Python...)

BUT what I can suggest you in such a case where the input is a known Object of type Student, use some serializable/deserializable form of user input like JSON.
This would also safe the User from entering inputs in a loop...
Thereby the user would enter an object of primitve JSON types like this:

```
{\"sFirstName\":\"TheFirstName\", 
\"sLastName\":\"TheLastname\",
\"iHWAve\" : 0,
\"iQuizAve\": 0, 
\"iTestAve\": 0
\"iProjectAve\":0}
```

(yeah I know the \" escaping is pretty uggly...maybe you can also omit the backslashes...but never tested out entering JSON over keyboard)

AND here some code how to deserialize this JSON with the GSON library to your Student:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the student as JSON: ");
String userInput = reader.nextLine();

Gson gson = new Gson();  
Student student = gson.fromJson(userInput , Student.class);
```

Obviously you would have to include GSON as library dependency...
Anyway Im pretty sure your task was just doing a serial execution of scanner prompts...

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the students FirstName: ");
String firstName = reader.nextLine();
.
.
.
System.out.println("Enter the student iProjectAve: ");
int iProjectAve = reader.nextInt();
```